# seconds in clock getting displayed after 5 seconds interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, clock, real-time-clock

I am working on a clock in Javascript in which seconds is getting displayed after every 5 seconds which I am 
not sure why.

The code which I have used for the clock is:

```
const suv = document.querySelector('#online-suv');
const suvLabel = document.querySelector('#online-suvLabel');

suv.title = suvLabel.title = headingFromDurationstamp(newT, true);
```

```
function headingFromDurationstamp(t, inSeconds) {

    let m = new Date(Number(t));
    let sac = ('0' + String(d.getHours())).substr(-2) + ':' + ('0' + String(d.getMinutes())).substr(-2);

    if (inSeconds) {

        sac += ':'  + ('0' + String(d.getSeconds())).substr(-2);
    }
    m = undef;

    return sac;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the JS above so that the seconds get displayed every second like a normal clock like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock).

Comment: where's your loop?

Comment: @ACD Which loop ?

Comment: how do you display multiple times? your code only runs once. how did you even come up with those logs?

Comment: and newT is? is it Date.now()?

Comment: @ACD That's not a loop. That is just an example to explain much better. The clock gets displayed once with seconds changing in 5 seconds interval.

Comment: so you want your clock to have a refresh rate of 5 seconds but you dont want it to skip seconds in display? Like 00:01 (5seconds later) 00:02 (5seconds later) 00:03?

Comment: FYI! setTimeout(startTime, 500) is a recursion.

Comment: I have edited my question. It should show as a normal clock. Let us consider this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock). In the link, it is a normal clock.

Comment: yeh. you might have wrote `setTimeout(startTime, 5000)` instead of `setTimeout(startTime, 500)`. 5k instead of 500

Comment: But in my case if I consider [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock) as an example, the seconds show up in a duration of 5 seconds like 9:00:00 9:00:05. Did you get my point ?

Comment: It is  just one clock.

Comment: So timeout every 5 seconds, not one....

Comment: yes..it timeouts every 5 seconds

Comment: Where is the timeout in your code?

Comment: Let me check stay tuned.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic works perfectly fine. You just have to change few variable misuse like you assigned `m` to new date and use `d` out of nowhere to get sac and some `d = undef` which i'm not sure what for.

Also please check your loop.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $('.time').html(headingFromDurationstamp(Date.now(), true));
}, 500);

function headingFromDurationstamp(t, inSeconds) {

  let d = new Date(Number(t));
  let sac = ('0' + String(d.getHours())).substr(-2) + ':' + ('0' + String(d.getMinutes())).substr(-2);

  if (inSeconds) {

    sac += ':' + ('0' + String(d.getSeconds())).substr(-2);
  }
  //d = undef;

  return sac;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="time">00:00:00</div>
```

Comment: I am checking where I have used interval.

Comment: I tried looking but I wasn't able to find it where setInterval function is used. In my website, at the front-end, I am getting the following html. Inside the title attribute clock is present. I am wondering what changes I need to make in your code (in your setInterval function). Your are using .html, I am not sure how I can use  attribute there.  

`<div id="online-suvLabel" class="active no-events" title="15:06:30" style="left: 100px;"></div>`

Comment: if you're using `title` attribute somehow, you can do: `$('#online-suvLabel').attr('title', headingFromDurationstamp(Date.now(), true));`

Comment: It did work but the seconds seems to flcker. I am not sure how I can reproduce.

Comment: thats because there's some loop running changing the time. if you really can't find it, change your div id to something else so the other loop can't update it.

Comment: If we write only this `setInterval(function() {
$('#online-suvLabel').attr('title');
}, 500);` whats gonna happen ?